# How to handle Facade in feature by package structure

Tags: spring, spring-boot, design-patterns, microservices

How can I structure my project if I have a facade?

The controller will call the facade to call the class in another package and the self package?

Like:

```
feature/
├── order/
│   ├── OrderController <== here calls Facade
│   ├── OrderService
└── facade/
│   ├── CheckoutFacade <== here calls orderService(go to facade and back to self package) and personService 
└── person/
    └── PersonService
```

Should I create a controller package separately of feature?

Comment: The Façade pattern is supposed to help simplify a sub-system (make access to it easier). I don't think you should re-design a sub-system because you're using a façade. Your question seems backwards to me for that reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could organise package as: [now I think it's totally wrong]

[EDIT] this below is a bit missleading

```
orderfeature/
├── OrderController <== here calls Facade public
└── service/
   ├── CheckoutFacade <== here calls orderService(go to facade and back to self package) and personService - public for test purpouse      
   ├── OrderService (might be package scope)
   └── PersonService (might be package scope)
```

[EDIT] this one is acceptable!

```
orderfeature/
├── OrderController <== here calls Facade public
├── CheckoutFacade <== here calls orderService(go to facade and back to self package) and personService - (might be package scope)      
├── OrderService (might be package scope)
└── PersonService (might be package scope)
```

with experience comes also some conclusions for now in my projects I have this kind of structure

the way I do it for now is:

```
orderfeature/
└── api/
   ├── OrderController <== PACKAGE SCOPE [autowiring CheckoutFacade and so on.., and there is no need to make it public]
└── exceptions/
   ├── ExampleException <== PUBLIC SCOPE 
└── dto/
   ├── ExampleDTO <== PUBLIC SCOPE [to communicate with facade]
├── CheckoutFacade <== PUBLIC SCOPE      
├── OrderService <== PACKAGE SCOPE [service is hidden]
├── PersonService <== PACKAGE SCOPE [service is hidden]
├── ExampleRepository <== PUBLIC SCOPE [repository interface is public]
├── ExampleRepositoryInMemory <== PACKAGE SCOPE [repository interface 
└── FeatureConfiguration <== PACKAGE SCOPE [ex spring bean config]
```

And i'am really happy